# Trycatch error handling in a vectorized way

Tags: r, try-catch, vectorization

I'm trying to calculate the interest rate that a person received on their loan based on the term, monthly payment, and original principal. For instance, a person might have a term of 120 months, with a monthly payment of $200 on a loan with original principal of $10000.

I'm using the `RATE` function from package `optiRum`. In the example above the interest rate will be `RATE(120, -200, 10000)` = 0.0175 (this is a monthly interest rate)

Now, there are cases where the interest rate calculation should fail. For instance, you can't compute the rate in cases when the `term*monthly_payment < original_principal`. For instance, `RATE(3, -200, 1000)` will correctly throw an error saying `rate > 0 is not TRUE`.

For the rows where the `RATE` throws an error, I need tryCatch to simply store an error message, otherwise it should compute the rate. Unfortunately, the behavior of tryCatch is to input the error message for all the rows. See the cases below for an example.

#### **Case 1:**

In the code below, I have 3 loans with term 6, monthly payment of 200, and starting principal of 1000. The interest rate for all 3 records should be 0.05472.

```
library(optiRum)
tryCatch(RATE(c(6,6,6), c(-200, -200, -200), c(1000, 1000, 1000)),
        error = function(e) "error")
```

**Output** : `[1] 0.05472 0.05472 0.05472`

#### **Case 2:**

In the code below, I have 2 records with term 6 and 1 record with term 1. The monthly payment for all records is 200, and starting principal of 1000. The interest rate for 2 records should be 0.05472, and for the last one it should just store an error message.

```
tryCatch(RATE(c(6,6,1), c(-200, -200, -200), c(1000, 1000, 1000)),
        error = function(e) "error")
```

**Output** : `[1] "error"`

The expected output is `"0.05472", "0.05472", "error"`, which does not match the actual output.

---

I have a solution that applies the `tryCatch` in a loop scenario, but this solution is not feasible when dealing with millions of rows. It would be very helpful is someone could show me how to vectorize the tryCatch behavior.

**Loopy loop tryCatch:**

```
rate_catch <- function (terms_duration, monthly_payment_amount, original_amount) {
  return(tryCatch(RATE(terms_duration, monthly_payment_amount, original_amount), error=function(e) NA))
}

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[i,4]<-rate_catch(df$terms_duration[i],
             -df$monthly_payment_amount[i],
             df$original_amount[i])
}
```

Comment: Seems to me that this is a problem with the RATE function,  which throws an ertor in case of wrong inputs instrad than setting output to NA.  If that's the case,  don't know if you can do much,  if you are not willing to modify or rewrite the function.

Comment: A possible workaround, if you already know which kind of inputs combinations are "illegal" (e.g., the ones where term*monthly_payment < original_principal), would be to find the offending rows beforehand, substitute their values with some dummy data (e.g., NA, or if it doesn't work some combination that gives as output a dummy value (i.e., a realistically impossible result), and then look for that dummy value in the output and change it to NA.

Comment: You can certainly make the loop faster - avoid repeated selections from the data frame and avoid replacing values in the data.frame; try to use apply instead; But as the first step I would check that one can actually process millions rows even in vectorized manner (use synthetic data that do not have errors and do not require tryCatch).

Comment: In addition to @LorenzoBusetto's suggestion of pre-function filtering, you might need to (a) rewrite `RATE` to put error-handling internal to the function, or (b) accept a solution that calls `RATE` once for each value (your `for` loop is one such solution, though `mapply` might also work). BTW: I suggest you use `NA` instead of `"error"`, since the latter will coerce a vector of numbers into all strings.

Comment: Thank you all the input! I'll shortly give a more detailed description within the question as to what things I tried and what worked.